# Objective-C accessing singleton's property causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a singleton class `KTTTeacherService` that has a single property `currentTeacher`. This property is `nil` initially and is updated with the static method `KTTTeacherService#updateCurrentTeacher`. After `currentTeacher` is updated, when I try to access it, my app crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

**`KTTTeacherService.h`**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "KTTeacher.h"

@interface KTTTeacherService : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) KTTeacher* currentTeacher;

+ (KTTTeacherService*)shared;
+ (KTTeacher*)currentTeacher;
+ (NSString*)apiKey;
+ (void)updateCurrentTeacher:(KTTeacher*) teacher;
- (KTTeacher*)retrieveCurrentTeacher;

@end
```

**`KTTTeacherService.m`**

```
#import "KTTTeacherService.h"
#import "KTTeacher.h"

static KTTTeacherService* _singleton = nil;

@implementation KTTTeacherService;

+ (KTTTeacherService*) shared {
  if(_singleton == nil) {
    _singleton = [[KTTTeacherService alloc] init];
  }
  return _singleton;
}

+ (KTTeacher*) currentTeacher {
  KTTTeacherService* shared = [KTTTeacherService shared];
  if(shared == nil) {
    return nil;
  }
  return [shared retrieveCurrentTeacher];
}

+ (NSString*) apiKey {
  KTTeacher* teacher = [KTTTeacherService currentTeacher];
  return teacher == nil ? nil : teacher.apiKey;
}

+ (void) updateCurrentTeacher:(KTTeacher*) teacher {
  [KTTTeacherService shared].currentTeacher = teacher;
}

- (KTTeacher*) retrieveCurrentTeacher {
  return _currentTeacher;
}

@end
```

**`KTTeacher.h`**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class KTClass, KTGroup, KTTeacherNote;

@interface KTTeacher : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * apiKey;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * serverIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * photoPathOnServer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * hashedPassword;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * salt;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *classes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *groups;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *notes;
@end

@interface KTTeacher (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addClassesObject:(KTClass *)value;
- (void)removeClassesObject:(KTClass *)value;
- (void)addClasses:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeClasses:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addNotesObject:(KTTeacherNote *)value;
- (void)removeNotesObject:(KTTeacherNote *)value;
- (void)addNotes:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeNotes:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addGroupsObject:(KTGroup *)value;
- (void)removeGroupsObject:(KTGroup *)value;
- (void)addGroups:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeGroups:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

**`KTTeacher.m`**

```
#import "KTTeacher.h"
#import "KTClass.h"
#import "KTTeacherNote.h"

@implementation KTTeacher

@dynamic apiKey;
@dynamic serverIdentifier;
@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;
@dynamic photoPathOnServer;
@dynamic username;
@dynamic hashedPassword;
@dynamic salt;
@dynamic classes;
@dynamic groups;
@dynamic notes;

@end
```

Where the crash happens:

```
KTTTeacherService* teacherService = [KTTTeacherService shared];

KTTeacher* currentTeacher = teacherService.currentTeacher;
```

Specifically here: `teacherService.currentTeacher`

Why is this happening? After doing some googling, I found some info about this error being caused by accessing references that have been garbage collected, but I don't understand why this variable would be garbage collected because the singleton keeps a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property written incorrectly. Use **strong, weak, retain** instead **assign**

property (nonatomic, assign) KTTeacher* currentTeacher;

Comment: Thank you. Changing `assign` to `strong` solved the issue. I'm still fairly new to Objective-C, so I'll do some research on these keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error and I could not. Create a project and put the classes KTTTeacherService, KTTeacher (empty class with the apiKey property) Everything works fine. **Therefore you must have the error in the KTTeacher class.**

In the viewDidLoad I have the following:

```
KTTTeacherService* teacherService = [KTTTeacherService shared];
// updateCurrentTeacher, for default is nil
KTTeacher *teacher = [[KTTeacher alloc] init];
[KTTTeacherService updateCurrentTeacher:teacher];
KTTeacher* currentTeacher = teacherService.currentTeacher
```

When you call currentTeacher method then, _currentTeacher (property) has a value now.

Comment: The crash happens when I try to access `teacherService.currentTeacher`. How could I be doing anything in the `KTTeacher` class that doesn't cause a compiler error but causes a crash when just accessing a value of the type `KTTeacher`?

Comment: I'll update my question with more information about the KTTeacher class though.